# Calculating future value with compound interest with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, finance

I'm trying to work on a script where the user inserts a monthly income and gets the future value with compound interest after 30 years. As it is now, I've assigned some values for testing purposes.

```
// Future Value
var investment = 800;
var annualRate = 2;
var monthlyRate = annualRate / 12 / 100;
var years = 30;
var months = years * 12;
var futureValue = 0;

for ( i = 1; i <= months; i++ ) {
    futureValue = futureValue + investment * Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, months);
}
```

Problem is, I'm actually building this from an Excel spreadsheet that's using the built-in FV() formula and when cross checking, my results are totally off... Any idea what I'm doing wrong since I'm not into finance math at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Math.pow` is unnecessary, since you are calculating and incrementing `futureValue` month by month. Simply multiply by `1 + monthlyRate`. You also want to add the current value of the investment to the new investment before multiplying:

```
for ( i = 1; i <= months; i++ ) {
   futureValue = (futureValue + investment) * (1 + monthlyRate);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also calculate this in one go with the following formula:

```
futureValue = investment * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, months) - 1) / monthlyRate;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That seems to do the trick, by using Math.floor I can get even closer to the Excel results. For some reason, I had this in mind: FV = PV * (1+i)^t which was totally wrong for what I was trying to do...

Comment: @AlexBerg that formula is for an yearly interest rate where t is the number of the year. What you calculate is for example if I lend you 100 dollars and you will give me after 3 years in one shot with interests. so pv is 100 and t is 3.

Answer (score 6):

Below is the code to calculate compound interest.

```js
function calculate() {
  p = document.getElementById("p").value;
  n = document.getElementById("n").value; // no. of compoundings per year
  t = document.getElementById("t").value; // no. of years
  r = document.getElementById("r").value;
  result = document.getElementById("result");

  // The equation is A = p * [[1 + (r/n)] ^ nt]
  A = (p * Math.pow((1 + (r / (n * 100))), (n * t)));

  // toFixed is used for rounding the amount with two decimal places.
  result.innerHTML = "The total amount is " + A.toFixed(2);

  result.innerHTML += "<br> The interest is " + (A.toFixed(2) - p).toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
div {
  display: table-row;
}

label,
input {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Compound Interest Calculation using jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Compound Interest Calculation Using jQuery</h1>
  <div> <label>Amount: </label> <input id="p"> </div>
  <div> <label>Rate (%): </label> <input id="r"> </div>
  <div> <label>No. of Years: </label> <input id="t"> </div>
  <div> <label>Compunding Times Per Year: </label> <input id="n" value="1"> </div>

  <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

  <p id="result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The DOM fetching and display is completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Also I found with this alternative:

```
function compoundInterest(principal, annual_rate, n_times, t_years) {
    return principal*(Math.pow(1 + annual_rate/n_times, n_times*t_years) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function FVcalc(PresentAmount,InterestRate,NumberOfYears) {
    var timescompound = 1;
    var AnnualInterestRate = (InterestRate/100)/timescompound;
    var Years= NumberOfYears

    var Periods=timescompound*Years;
    var NumPayments=Periods;
    var Prin=PresentAmount;

    MonthPayment=Math.floor((Prin)*(Math.pow((1+AnnualInterestRate),(Periods)))*100)/100;
    FVFactor=(Math.pow((1+AnnualInterestRate),(Periods)))
    return MonthPayment
}
```

http://www.uic.edu/classes/actg/actg500/pfvatutor.htm

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any case, note that `period` has a benchmark of 1 of a year so for instance every 6 months `period = 2`, 4 months `period = 3` etc...

```
var init = 500000
var years = 30
var compound = 1
var interest = 3.99
var period= 2
var total = 0



function CInterest(){
    for(let i=0; i<years*12; i++){
     
        if(i%(12/period) === 0){
            compound*=(1+((interest/100)/period))
        }
    }  
    total= init*compound
    }


    CInterest()
    console.log("total: ",total)
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is my way of writing code for compound interest**

```
function call()
    {
        var A = Principle;
        var B = Interest;
        var C = Years;
        var D = 0;
        var E = A*B/100;
        D+=E;
        var f=E+A;
        document.write("0 year: Interest "+E+" Principal: "+f);
        document.write("<br />");
        for (var i=1; i<C; i++)
        {
            E=f*B/100;
            D+=E;
            f=E+f;
            document.write(i+"year: Interest "+E+" Principal:"+f);
            document.write("<br />");
        }

    return false;
    }
```