# JavaScript - Inflation/Escalation with Total over X years

Tags: javascript

I've been building a JS calculator to help with annual fees, but I'm struggling with one part.

There's a field that should show the total of a yearly fee which increases by X% per-year over Y years.

A bit hard to explain, so below is an example:

Person A has a salary of **£24,000** which increases every year by **3.5%**. We need to figure out the total Person A has been paid over **7.373** years.

If I did this in a FOR loop, it works fine if the years are just integers, however I need a solution for floats and I'm not sure how to approach this - we need to figure out the total over 7.373 years and not just 7 (just an example, it could be any number of years).

Here's the test code that works fine using integers:

```
year = 7;
money = 24000;
num = 0;
percent = 1 + (3.5 / 100);
for(y = 1; y <= year; y++) {
    num = num + 1;
    money = money * interest
    console.log('Year '+ num + ' - ' + money);
    // other stuff
}
```

The resulting output would look like:

Year 1 - 24,840.00
Year 2 - 25,709.40
Year 3 - 26,609.23
Year 4 - 27,540.55
Year 5 - 28,504.47
Year 6 - 29,502.13
Year 7 - 30,534.70

What I actually need is the total sum of all of those years (ie. 193,240.48), and not just to calculate against 7 years, but 7.373 years (or whatever defined float is entered).

Comment: If you need to have access to those separate years later, you can store them in an array, and from there you can calculate their sum quite easily. If you need help with that, please let me know.

Comment: That's not an issue, its that I cannot use a FOR loop when calculating against floats.

Comment: You can do this [without a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712617/542251)

Comment: If nothing else, just a simple math can get you there (although I don't think this is the best possible approach for this kind of problem). If you know that for 7 years the result is `30,534.70`, you can calculate the amount for 7.373 as `(7.337*30,534.70) / 7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate one more year. In this example you need year 8. Then you can take the percentage of the year and add it to the sum.

In your loop you can use `Math.ceil(year)`. This will round the year up, so with years of `7.373` you will get 8 loops. You can test for this last year and adjust the percentage accordingly:

```js
let year = 7.373;
let money = 24000;
let num = 0;
let total = 0
let percent = 1 + (3.5 / 100);
for (let y = 1; y <= Math.ceil(year); y++) {
  num = num + 1;
  money = money * percent
  if (y > year) { // year 8
    // the sum will only increas .373 of year 8
    money *= 1 - (y - year)
    console.log(`Calculating ${1- (y-year)} of year ${y}`)
  }

  //  increment total
  total += money

  console.log('Year ' + num + ' - ' + money.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'GBP'
  }));
  // other stuff
}
console.log(`Total: after ${year} years:`, total.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'GBP'
}))
```

Also, not really addressing it here because it's a different question, but you need to be careful with money and floats because rounding errors can lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating an array of those values and then summing up to 7 years, and then adding the 8th year as a .373 fraction of that year.

```
const year = 8;
let money = 24000;
const percent = 1 + (3.5 / 100);
let arrayOfYears = []

for(y = 1; y <= year; y++) {
    money = money * interest
    arrayOfYears.push(money)
    console.log('Year '+ y + ' - ' + money);
    // other stuff
}

let sum = arrayOfYears.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
    if (idx < 7) {
        return acc + cur
    } else {
        return acc + (cur * 0.373)
    }
}, 0)

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The specification of your problem leaves some interpretation so different possibilities. Usually increases after 1 year, i.e at the end of the full year there's an increment. Also as you are applying the whole percentage to a year the fractional year can be a fraction of the salary at end of year 7. The other way interest is calculated could be daily but that's not what your example showed. See this example below. Note the discussion above about rounding etc with floats to decimals and introduction of errors. In the code below it maybe necessary to fix to 2 decimal places at various stages to ensure accuracy but you hopefully get the idea.

```
        //Could round or make to fixed number of decimal places
        //the calculation maybe better to 2 decimal places i.e sprinkle with parseFloat(n.toFixed(2))
        function toDecStr(n) {
            return n.toLocaleString('en-GB',{minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2});
        }

        let targetYears = 7.373
        let startingSalary = 24000.00;
        let annualIncrease = 0.035; //3.5% increase, presumably at the end of each year
        let wholeYears = Math.trunc(targetYears);
        let fractionOfYear = targetYears - wholeYears; //Could round to a number of decimal places
        console.log("Whole years:%s + fraction of a year: %s",wholeYears,fractionOfYear);
        //calulate the whole number of years
        let totalSalary = startingSalary;
        let previousSalary = startingSalary
        console.log('Salary earned in year n and total salary to date:');
        console.log('Year %s = %s',1,toDecStr(startingSalary), toDecStr(totalSalary));
        for(let i = 2; i <= wholeYears; i++) {
            let newSalary = previousSalary * (1.0 + annualIncrease);
            totalSalary += newSalary; //At end of year i
            console.log('Year %s = %s %s', i, toDecStr(newSalary), toDecStr(totalSalary));
            previousSalary = newSalary;
        }
        // + Fractional year
        let earningsInPartialYear = previousSalary * fractionOfYear;
        totalSalary += earningsInPartialYear;
        console.log('Year %s %s', targetYears, toDecStr(earningsInPartialYear), toDecStr(totalSalary));
        //Note no salary increase in a fractional year (until the end the year)
```

Gives:

```
Whole years:7 + fraction of a year: 0.3730000000000002
Salary earned in year n and total salary to date:
Year 1 = 24,000.00 24,000.00
Year 2 = 24,840.00 48,840.00
Year 3 = 25,709.40 74,549.40
Year 4 = 26,609.23 101,158.63
Year 5 = 27,540.55 128,699.18
Year 6 = 28,504.47 157,203.65
Year 7 = 29,502.13 186,705.78
Year 7.373 11,004.29 197,710.07
```